# How to calculate bayes in TrueSkill

Tags: algorithm

**Hello!**

I'm trying to understand how TrueSkill works mostly for the easiest case of 1vs1. I'm using mainly the original paper and "[Computing Your Skill](http://www.moserware.com/2010/03/computing-your-skill.html)". However i get confuse a los when the factor graph appears. I think i first need to understand the logic of all these and then see how the math is use for a less computational cost.
So to start off, need to confirm, the factor graph is only a tool to make a less computational cost of the math involve o TrueSkill?

Then, i have a Gaussian with mean s1 with variance o1, and the same for player 2. Then we also create a Gaussian with same mean but with a variance of the game beta. Also we know the result of the match.
So theoretically without using message or sum-product, how its Bayes here? How i compute my prior, likelihood and evidence? There is an final expression of sums or multiplications of Gaussians? I missing something else?  Its make sense what i'm asking?

My idea was something like this: suppose that player 1 has larger skill than player 2, and player 1 wins. So Posterior = new Gaussian of skill with new variance. That with Bayes is likelihood*prior/evidence. Where prior is the first Gaussian with mean skill and its variance. Posterior is de subtract of the Gaussian performance of player 1 with 2. And the evidence is the actual percentage of winning that player one had with player 2. There is something of true of what i'm saying?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea in language that may be more familiar to you.

Our prior for each player is that their true skills have a prior of a bell shaped curve with known mean and standard deviation.  Our prior for the match is that the skills of the one player is independent from the skills of the other.  Our prior for the outcome of the match is a specific probability of win/draw/loss for each skill difference.

You play the match and record the outcome.

Given that observation and our prior distribution for the skill difference, we have a posterior distribution for the skill difference.  Walking it back through the chain, we get posterior bell shaped curves for the skills of each player.  We therefore get a new mean and standard deviation for each.

Now notice that in the math, the posterior distributions for the players are now correlated.  But if we tried to keep track of these correlations we'd be updating a Bayesian net, and that is an NP-complete problem.  So we lie and pretend that they are now uncorrelated.  This lie is called *naive* Bayes, and in practice the correlations tend to cancel each other out well enough that it works well.

Does that help?

Comment: mm more or less. I trying to get an final expression(i don't know if its posible) of multiplications or sums(or subtract) this probabilities. Like de new probability of skill of player 1 by winning to player to is p(s1|s2,win)= prob of winning*prob skill1
and maybe prob of winning is comulative of [N(s1,std1)*N(performance1)-N(st2,std2)*N(performance2)].

Answer (score 0):

You can focus on just one player to really simplify things. As you mentioned, the model is using Bayes Theorem, `posterior = likelihood*prior/evidence`. Let `A` be the random variable of a player's skill (in the paper, the normal distribution with a mean of `s_i`), and `B` be the random variable for game outcome.

```
P(A) = probability of skill (prior)
P(B|A) = game outcome probability based on skill (likelihood)
P(B) = probability of outcome (marginal likelihood or evidence)
P(A|B) = probability of skill, given the outcome (posterior)
```

The model in the paper much more complicated because there are multiple players, and teams of varying sizes, but this simplification shows where Bayes Theorem is used.